# PyCharm: List all usages of all methods of a class

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, intellij-idea, pycharm

I'm aware that I can use 'Find Usages' to find what's calling a method in a class.
Is there a way of doing this for all methods on a given class? (or indeed all methods in file)

Use Case: I'm trying to refactor a god class, that should almost certainly be several classes. It would be nice to be able to see what subset of god class methods, the classes that interact with it use. It seems like PyCharm has done the hard bit of this, but doesn't let me scale it up.

I'm using PyCharm 2016.1.2

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206666319-See-all-callers-of-all-methods-of-a-class

Comment: AFAIK there is no such option in PyCharm. Further, I am not sure I can see the benefit of such a feature: say you have a class with two methods and you had this feature, and it would say that these two methods are used 146 times in your project. Now lets say that one method is used only once and the other method is used 145 times. What does the number 146 mean now? What can you do with such an information ?

Comment: I'd like to be told: [classes] use method A, [classes] use Method B and/or ClassA uses [methods], ClassB uses [different set of methods], ClassC uses [another different set of methods] etc.
Then I'd be able to more easily figure out if there are distinct subsets of functionality in my god class, which would help me refactor it.

Comment: I would argue that the grouping should be done by groups of methods that have related functionalities, *not* by the usage. Doing the cleanup top-bottom might help you clean up other classes as well, while doing it with the original approach (group by usage - which is bottom-up) might create unnecessary coupling between code modules/classes that shouldn't be coupled.

Answer (score -1):

This is possible, but you have to deal with abstraction, otherwise Pycharm doesn't know the method in question belongs to your specific class.  AKA - [Type Hinting](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/type-hinting-in-pycharm.html?origin=old_help)

Any instance of that method being called in an abstraction layer which does not have type hinting will not be found.

Example:

```py
#The class which has the method you're searching for.
class Inst(object):
    def mymethod(self):
        return

#not the class your looking for, but it too has a method of the same name.
class SomethingElse(object):
    def mymethod(self):
        return

#Option 1 -- Assert hinting
def foo(inst):
    assert isinstance(inst, Inst)
    inst.mymethod()

#Option 2 --  docstring hinting
def bar(inst):
    """

    :param inst: 
    :type inst: Inst 
    :return: 
    :rtype: 
    """
    inst.mymethod()
```

Answer (score -1):

Nowadays it would be rather easy for Pycharm to use Python 3.6 type hints and match function calls "correctly", as type hints are part of Python 3.5/3.6 language. Of course partial type hints in a big software cause some compromises when resolving the targets of the method calls.

Here is an example, how type hints makes it very easy to do type inferencing logic and resolve the correct target of the call.

```
def an_example():
    a: SoftagramAnalysisAction = SoftagramAnalysisAction(
        analysis_context=analysis_context,
        preprocessors=list(preprocessors),
        analyzers=list(analyzers),
        analysis_control_params=analysis_control_params)
    output = a.run()
```

In above example, local variable a is specially marked to have type SoftagramAnalysisAction which makes it clear that run() call below targets to the run method of that class (or any of its possible subclasses).

The current version (2018.1) does not resolve these kind of calls correctly but I hope that will change in the future.